# With Aspose, how to get a table node after inserthtml?

Tags: .net, ms-word, aspose

I'm using the Aspose library to format a Word document.

After inserting a html table at a bookmark with `DocumentBuilder.InsertHtml()`, I would like to **retrieve the Aspose node for this table**.

But when iterate through the nodes around the bookmark I can't find the table, even though the total number of tables in the document is correctly incremented. Is there another way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can meet this requirement by implementing **INodeChangingCallback interface**. Here is code example:

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + @"input.docx");
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

builder.MoveToBookmark("tbl");

HandleNodeChanging handler = new HandleNodeChanging();
doc.NodeChangingCallback = handler;
builder.InsertHtml("<table border='1'><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr></table>");

foreach (Table table in handler.InsertedTables)
{
    // Your logic here
}    

doc.Save(MyDir + @"15.9.0.docx");
```

And the definition of class 'HandleNodeChanging' which implements INodeChangingCallback interface is as follows:

```
public class HandleNodeChanging : INodeChangingCallback
{
    void INodeChangingCallback.NodeInserted(NodeChangingArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Node.NodeType == NodeType.Table)
            mInsertedTables.Add(args.Node);
    }

    void INodeChangingCallback.NodeInserting(NodeChangingArgs args)
    {
        // Do Nothing
    }

    void INodeChangingCallback.NodeRemoved(NodeChangingArgs args)
    {
        // Do Nothing
    }

    void INodeChangingCallback.NodeRemoving(NodeChangingArgs args)
    {
        // Do Nothing
    }

    public List<Node> InsertedTables
    {
        get { return mInsertedTables; }
    }

    private readonly List<Node> mInsertedTables = new List<Node>();
}
```

Hope, this helps.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thanks! I could retrieve the inserted nodes with this method.